# Ошибка кластеризатора маркеров в api 3.0

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi, кластеризация

делаю тест согласно https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/3.0/ref/packages/clusterer/index.html.

Постоянно получаю ошибку

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: clusterByGrid is not a function

```
ymaps3.ready.then(init);
            
    function init(){

    const {YMapClusterer, clusterByGrid} = ymaps3.import('@yandex/ymaps3-clusterer@0.0.1');

    const contentPin = document.createElement('div');
    contentPin.innerHTML = '<img src="./pin.svg" />';


    myMap.addChild(new ymaps3.YMapDefaultSchemeLayer());
    myMap
    .addChild(new ymaps3.YMapFeatureDataSource({id: 'my-source'}))
    .addChild(new ymaps3.YMapLayer({source: 'my-source', type: 'markers', zIndex: 1800}));


                    const coordinates = [
                      [37.64, 55.76],
                      [37.63, 55.7],
                      [37.43, 55.69],
                      [37.47, 55.68],
                      [38.53, 58.6],
                      [37.59, 55.71],
                      [37.5, 55.63],
                      [37.52, 55.57],
                      [37.52, 58.57],
                      [40.52, 58.57]
                    ];
                    
                    const marker = (feature) =>
                      new ymaps3.YMapMarker(
                        {
                          coordinates: feature.geometry.coordinates,
                          source: 'my-source'
                        },
                        contentPin.cloneNode(true)
                      );

                    const cluster = (coordinates, features) =>
                      new ymaps3.YMapMarker(
                        {
                          coordinates,
                          source: 'my-source'
                        },
                        circle(features.length).cloneNode(true)
                      );

                    function circle(count) {
                      const circle = document.createElement('div');
                      circle.classList.add('circle');
                      circle.innerHTML = `
                            <div class="circle-content">
                                <span class="circle-text">${count}</span>
                            </div>
                        `;
                      return circle;
                    }

                    const points = coordinates.map((lnglat, i) => ({
                      type: 'Feature',
                      id: i,
                      geometry: {coordinates: lnglat},
                      properties: {name: 'Point of issue of orders'}
                    }));

                    const clusterer = new YMapClusterer({
                            method: clusterByGrid({gridSize: 64}),
                            features: points,
                            marker,
                            cluster
                        });

                        ymaps3.addChild(clusterer);
}
```

Comment: А вы выведите в консоль `clusterByGrid` и посмотрите, что это, собственно. Ну или лучше в отладчике посмотрите, что туда возвращается. А где вы такой пример подсмотрели?

Comment: В консоли - Uncaught ReferenceError: clusterByGrid is not defined.    Пример по ссылке (я указал в первой строке сообщения). https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/3.0/ref/packages/clusterer/index.html.

Comment: Ну вот у меня впечатление, что `ymaps3.import` возвращает только одно значение, а второе значение остаётся не заполненным. Надо видимо в самом `YMapClusterer` нужную функцию искать.